# Can HMM, MRF, or CRF be used to classify the state of a single observation, not the entire observation sequence?

Tags: markov-chain, sequence-modeling, time-series, hidden-markov-model

I learn that the **Viterbi** algorithm used for Hidden Markov Model (**HMM**) can classify a sequence of hidden states from the corresponding observations; Markov Random Field (**MRF**) and Conditional Random Field (**CRF**) can also do it.

Can these algorithms be used to classify a single future state?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible and is exactly what a [Markov process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain) aims to accomplish.

The [Hidden Markov Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model) can be considered a simple dynamic Bayesian network. This means that it will generate a probabilistic outcome for a number of states (classes) given a sequence of inputs.

This can be used for a classification task based on a threshold probability to make a confirmed decision.

Let's take a simple example

[image: Example]

The above example is a model to determine  how a person will be feeling given some sample data of the previous days.

```
# Sample data
data = ['Healthy', 'Healthy', 'Fever']
```

Using this data, it's possible to calculate the probability of each possible state (outcome).

```
# Probability after 2 Healthy and 1 Fever day
P = 0.6 * 0.7 * 0.3

# Final day state 'Fever'
# Calculating probabilities for each state
Dizzy  = P * 0.6
Cold   = P * 0.3
Normal = P * 0.1
```

We can calculate the probability of each state and this will be unique for every unique sequence of historical data.

Comment: Do you have example code?

Comment: Code for this example? Or in general? The issue is that HMMs are not easy to generate. The probabilities, specified in the example are dummies, in a real use case, those values will have to be computed statistically from a large dataset before the model can be used.

Comment: code in general is fine. I’ve tried a python package, but I can only do decoding to get a sequence of states, while I want to get the state of a single input.